# Query the CnosDB stream table returns error 'No installed planner was able to convert the custom node to an execution plan'

Tags: cnosdb

I wanna query aggregated data faster so I'm trying cnosdb stream table, but there are some errors that makes me confused.

> CnosDB: main aa70bf1c (2023-07-04)
>
> Document: https://docs.cnosdb.com/en/latest/reference/sql.html#stream

#### Create table `cpu`

```sql
CREATE TABLE cpu (usage_system double, usage_user double, TAGS(cpu));
```

#### Create stream table `cpu_1min`

```sql
CREATE STREAM TABLE cpu_1min(time TIMESTAMP, usage_system double, usage_user double)
    WITH (DB='telegraf', TABLE='cpu', EVENT_TIME_COLUMN='time')
    ENGINE=tskv;
```

#### Insert some data in table `cpu`

```rust
INSERT INTO cpu(time, cpu, usage_system, usage_user) VALUES
    ('2023-07-09T11:00:00', 'cpu0', 0.1, 0.9),
    ('2023-07-09T11:00:10', 'cpu0', 0.2, 0.8),
    ('2023-07-09T11:00:20', 'cpu0', 0.3, 0.7),
    ('2023-07-09T11:01:00', 'cpu0', 0.4, 0.6),
    ('2023-07-09T11:01:10', 'cpu0', 0.5, 0.5),
    ('2023-07-09T11:01:20', 'cpu0', 0.6, 0.4),
    ('2023-07-09T11:02:00', 'cpu0', 0.7, 0.3),
    ('2023-07-09T11:02:10', 'cpu0', 0.8, 0.2),
    ('2023-07-09T11:02:20', 'cpu0', 0.9, 0.1);
```

#### Query stream table `cpu` and `cpu_1min`

```sql
> SELECT * FROM cpu;
+---------------------+------+--------------+------------+
| time                | cpu  | usage_system | usage_user |
+---------------------+------+--------------+------------+
| 2023-07-09T11:00:00 | cpu0 | 0.1          | 0.9        |
| 2023-07-09T11:00:10 | cpu0 | 0.2          | 0.8        |
| 2023-07-09T11:00:20 | cpu0 | 0.3          | 0.7        |
| 2023-07-09T11:01:00 | cpu0 | 0.4          | 0.6        |
| 2023-07-09T11:01:10 | cpu0 | 0.5          | 0.5        |
| 2023-07-09T11:01:20 | cpu0 | 0.6          | 0.4        |
| 2023-07-09T11:02:00 | cpu0 | 0.7          | 0.3        |
| 2023-07-09T11:02:10 | cpu0 | 0.8          | 0.2        |
| 2023-07-09T11:02:20 | cpu0 | 0.9          | 0.1        |
+---------------------+------+--------------+------------+

> SELECT * FROM cpu_1min;
422 Unprocessable Entity, details: {"error_code":"010001","error_message":"Datafusion: Error during planning: No installed planner was able to convert the custom node to an execution plan: StreamScan: [cpu_1min.time,cpu_1min.usage_system,cpu_1min.usage_user]"}
```

##### What I expected

```sql
> SELECT * FROM cpu_1min;
+---------------------+--------------+------------+
| time                | usage_system | usage_user |
+---------------------+--------------+------------+
| 2023-07-09T11:00:00 | 0.1          | 0.9        |
| 2023-07-09T11:00:10 | 0.2          | 0.8        |
| 2023-07-09T11:00:20 | 0.3          | 0.7        |
| 2023-07-09T11:01:00 | 0.4          | 0.6        |
| 2023-07-09T11:01:10 | 0.5          | 0.5        |
| 2023-07-09T11:01:20 | 0.6          | 0.4        |
| 2023-07-09T11:02:00 | 0.7          | 0.3        |
| 2023-07-09T11:02:10 | 0.8          | 0.2        |
| 2023-07-09T11:02:20 | 0.9          | 0.1        |
+---------------------+--------------+------------+
```